# If $A$ is Noetherian, then every fractional ideal is of the form $x^{-1} \frak{a}$ for some ideal $\frak{a}$ of $A$

Tags: commutative-algebra

> [Statement]
> If $A$ is Noetherian, then every fractional ideal is of the form  $x^{-1} \frak{a}$ for some ideal $\frak{a}$ of $A$, $x \in A$.

---

[Attempt]

I find this in Atiyah Macdonald Commutative algebra, Chapter 9 ,page 96 , Fractional ideals.

They say if  $A$ is Noetherian, then every fractional ideal is of the form  $x^{-1} \frak{a}$ for some ideal $\frak{a}$ of $A$, $x \in A$ so every fractional ideal is finitely generated.

It is okay "so ever fractional ideal is finitely generated" because $A$ is noetherian so ideal $\frak{a}$ is finitely generated.

However, how to show above statement?

Let $M$ be fractional ideal. Then by definition, there is $\frac{b}{a} \in K:=\text{Frac}(A)$ such that $\frac{a}{b} M \subseteq A $, so $M \subseteq \frac{b}{a}A$.

What is next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{m_i\}_{i\in I}$ generate $M$ as an $A$-module. Then as $m_i A\subseteq M\subseteq\frac{b}{a}A,$ it follows that $m_i\in\frac{b}{a}A.$ Thus, for each $i,$ we may write $$m_i = \frac{b_i}{a},$$ with $b_i\in A.$ This implies that
\begin{align*}
M &= \sum_{i\in I} m_i A\\
&=\sum_{i\in I}\frac{b_i}{a}A\\
& = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{i\in I}b_i A.
\end{align*}
But now $\sum_{i\in I}b_i A$ is simply the ideal of $A$ generated by the $b_i,$ so we are done.

Comment: Awesome, it is generally true if $A$ is not noetherian.

Comment: @hew It will still be true that $M = \frac1a\mathfrak{a}$ for some ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq A$ and element $a\in A,$ but it need not be true that $M$ is finitely generated. As an example, take any ideal which is not finitely generated and consider it as a fractional ideal.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's what i'm saying. Every fractional ideal is of the form $\frac{1}{a} \frak{a}$...  very nice. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hew You're welcome! I misread your last comment as "is it" instead of "it is."